# In a 10 by 10 matrix, why does this array notation not work?

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to know why doesn't my following code output a 1. on the left and right side of the matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10
def dungeon(N):
    dungeon = np.zeros((N, N))
    # Top and bottom
    dungeon[0] = 1
    dungeon[-1] = 1
    
    # Right side
    #dungeon[1][0] = 1
    #dungeon[2][0] = 1
    # etc...
    dungeon[0:3][0]
    
    print(dungeon)
```

Why doesn't dungeon[0:3][0] output 1.'s on the left column? How can I fix this without individually writing dungeon[1][0], dungeon[2][0], etc...?

Comment: Why should it? You didn't set the left and right side, did you? (besides you can still do a simple for loop)

Comment: You can use `np.pad` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating a 10x10 Matrix.

`dungeon[0] = 1` sets all the elements in the 1st row to 1.

`dungeon[-1] = 1` sets all the elements in the last row to 1.

You didn't set the right and left sides.

There are two ways to generate a 10x10 matrix which contains 0s in the center and 1s at the sides:

```
dungeon = np.ones((10, 10))
dungeon [1:-1, 1:-1] = 0
```

OR

```
dungeon = np.zeros((10, 10))
dungeon[0:N,0:1] = 1
dungeon[0:N,-1:N] = 1
dungeon[0:1,0:N] = 1
dungeon[-1:N,0:N] = 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the transpose!

```
import numpy as np
  
N = 10
def dungeon(N):
    dungeon = np.zeros((N, N))
    # Top and bottom
    dungeon[0] = 1
    dungeon[-1] = 1

    # Right and left side
    dungeon = dungeon.T
    dungeon[0] = 1
    dungeon[-1] = 1

    print(dungeon)
```